# What is the difference between SD, SDHC and SDXC?

Tags: storage, sd-card

What is the difference between SD, SDHC and SDXC memory cards?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a nutshell:

- SD - standard speed, 4 GB capacity limit
- SDHC - high speed (suitable for recording video), 32 GB capacity limit
- SDXC - supports even higher speeds, 2 TB capacity limit